# Why memcpy() fails copying elements of an array in the same array but with an offset

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm trying to copy the content of an array inside itself but with an offset (or from an offset). For example:

```
int main(void) {
    char a[4] = { 'a', 'b' , 'c', 'd' }, b[4], c[4];

    memcpy(b, a, 4);
    memcpy(c, b, 4);

    memcpy(b, b + 1, 3);
    memcpy(c + 1, c, 3);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%c", b[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%c", c[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

gives the following output:

```
bcdd
aaaa
```

and I was expecting

```
bcdd
aabc
```

The first `memcpy` it works but as the second doesn't it looks to me that it is inconsistent so I'm doing something wrong.

I can't understand what am I doing wrong. Why does it fails. Also, will this still happen if I try to do the same but for an array of structs for example ?

Comment: For **overlapping** memory do not use `memcpy` but use [`memmove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/). The error for `c` is caused by a `for` like copying in the wrong direction.

Comment: When a routine is not working the way you want, find and read its documentation.

Comment: @JoopEggen, thank you! What do you mean with _for like copying in the wrong direction_?

Comment: When one would use a for loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) c[i+1] = c[i];` one would get that wrong `aaaa`. The other direction would do here: `for (int i = 3-1; i >= 0; --i) c[i+1] = c[i];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 2018 C standard specifies `memcpy` in clause 7.24.2.1. Paragraph 2 says:

> … If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

To move data within an array, use `memmove`. Its specification, in 7.24.2.2 2 says:

> Copying takes place as if the `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` are first copied into a temporary array of `n` characters that does not overlap the objects pointed to by `s1` and `s2`, and then the `n` characters from the temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by `s1`.

(`s1` is the destination, `s2` is the source, and `n` is the number of bytes to be copied.)

Comment: I didn't knew this was relating to overlaping objejcts. Thanks. So there is no technical explanation about why actually this fails, excepting that the standard mention it?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu: The routine does not fail; its behavior conforms to its documentation. As for the reason it does not work the way you want, undoubtedly it is written, at least in part, as some simple loop like `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) s1[i] = s2[i];`. So `memcpy(c+1, c, 3)` is executed as `c[1] = c[0]; c[2] = c[1]; c[3] = c[2];`. In contrast, `memmove` must examine its pointers and decide whether to copy in the forward direction or the backward direction or even use some other method.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu: (Also note that simple loop would be just part of a good `memcpy` implementation. A good implementation will have code to handle large copies using SIMD code, different cases for different alignment, and so on.)

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu - whether or not `memcpy` handles overlapping regions correctly is implementation-dependant. Only `memmove` is guaranteed to handle overlaps properly.